# javascript function, can't figure out why it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file called test2.js

```
function LoadCSV() {

var csv = require('csv-parser')
var fs = require('fs')

fs.createReadStream('Branches.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', function (data) {
    //console.log('Name: %s City: %s', data.Name, data.City);

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (data.City);
  })
}
```

Then I have an html

```
    <html>
<body>
  <script src="test2.js"></script>
  <p id="output">Output</p>
  <button onclick="LoadCSV()">Count</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, it doesn't display the csv data.  I can't figure out why.  I tested it with another javascript called test1.js and it works

```
function LoadCSV() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ("test");
}
```

Comment: You’re using `require`, but you haven’t linked any JS file to define it.

Comment: `.pipe(csv())` is wrong: you call `csv()` immediately, while you want to *pass* the function, not *call* it: `.pipe(csv)`

Comment: Are you trying to use a node.js `fs` module on the client side? That simply cannot work.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use node.js on client side.  How can I make it work?  I'm new to javascript / node.  Any help is appreciated.